# tinyMCE selector not load textarea initially

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, tinymce

I am using tinymce with cold fusion. I have multiple textareas and I want tinymce to apply to all of them. The textareas get the data from database. My problem is that only the first textarea gets populated when the page is first loaded, and the rest are left blank. However, they are all populated with data when I refresh the page. I tried to change selector to mode in the init function, all textareas are populuated when the page is first loaded, but the content lost the style (html format) that I get from selector. Below is the sample code. How can I get all textareas populated when the page is first loaded while keeping the html style in the content? Appreciate your input!

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    tinymce.init({ 
        selector: "textarea", 
        convert_fonts_to_spans : true,
        autoresize: true, 
        plugins: [ 
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print", 
            "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen", 
            "insertdatetime contextmenu paste moxiemanager",         
        ], 
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",  
        save_enablewhendirty: true, 
        save_onsavecallback: function() {console.log("Save");} 
    }); 
    </script> 

<!---Select from database--->
<cfquery name="message" datasource="#Datasource#" username="#dbuser#" password="#dbpasswd#">
query goes here...
</cfquery>
...

<cfoutput>      
<cfform name="news" action="..." method="POST">

    <!---Form Fields: textarea as selector--->

     <textarea name="msgHeader" cols="1" rows="1" style="width:100%">#message.msgHeader#</textarea>
     <textarea name="msgText" cols="50" rows="8" style="width:100%" >#message.msgText#</textarea>      
     <textarea name="msgHeader1" cols="1" rows="1" style="width:100%">#message.msgHeader1#</textarea>
     <textarea name="msgText1"  cols="50" rows="8" style="width:100%" >#message.msgText1#</textarea>
     <textarea name="msgText2"  cols="50" rows="8" style="width:100%" >#message.msgText2#</textarea>
...                                         
</cfform>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: If you reverse the order of the first two textarea tags, which one gets populated?

Comment: Dan, interesting, that when I revers the order, all fields are populated, however all the content lost the style. It is the same result as I got when I change selector to mode in the init function. Any idea why?

Comment: I have no idea why that would be.  I always do functionality first, appearance last.  I also don't use tinymce.  I go with either <textarea> or <cftextarea>

Answer (score 0):

Try giving an id (same as the name) to all your textares. Tinymce doen't initialize textareas to tinymces if they have the same id.

Comment: I tried to add the id to each textarea, still got the same result, that only the first textarea is populated.

Comment: this seems wierd. can you create a tinymce fiddle (http://fiddle.tinymce.com/) for this and post he link?